# My objects' members change when I call their methods

Tags: c++

I have an object in C++ with several properties initially set to `nullptr`, the idea being that I can tell when I reach the edge of what I have thus far defined. For example, I can chain `Node`s together into a linked list, and detect the end of the list by comparing to `nullptr`:

```
class Node{
public:
  Node* next;
  bool val;
  Node(bool v){val=v; next=nullptr;}
  void append(bool v){
    if (next==nullptr){
      next=&Node(v);
    }else{
      next->append(v);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem being that I keep getting Read Access Violations. When I step through line-by-line in Visual Studio, I see the same thing immediately before every failure: in one stack frame `next` is set up properly, with 0x00000000 for its own successor, but when I call `next->append(v);`, suddenly `next` is a random pointer like 0x01010101 or 0x00000001, which isn't `nullptr`, and so the code tries to call `append` on it and dies because that address does not hold a `Node`.
To Recap: `*next.next==nullptr`, but after calling `next.append(v);` something changes and `next!=nullptr`.

Comment: `next = new Node(v);` What you have now is taking the address of a temporary value that is immediately destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to dynamically allocate that object. You're using a temporary which falls out of scope on the very next line, and any references to that are invalidated, meaning your `next` pointer is now garbage.

The easy fix is:

```
void append(bool v) {
  if (next == nullptr) {
    next = new Node(v);
  } else {
    next->append(v);
  }
}
```

Where that does an allocation using `new` and places that value appropriately.

It's important to note that when you allocate with `new` your code is responsible for releasing that memory with `delete`. In other words, you are now obligated to create a destructor that unwinds all of your allocations.

It's worth noting that your constructor isn't correctly expressed, it should look like:

```
Node(bool v) : val(v), next(nullptr) { }
```

Where that makes use of constructor lists. This ensures that the values aren't first defaulted and then immediately assigned by effectively re-defining what the defaults are.